# Using theme attributes in a color selector in <API 21

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a state list color resource which uses theme attributes, i.e. button_background_tint.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:color="?android:attr/colorBackground"/>
</selector>
```

And apply it to my FloatingActionButton background tint with `app:backgroundTint="@color/button_background_tint"`

The button looks fine in API 21 or greater, but below API 21 the background is red no matter its state (even though `?android:attr/colorBackground` is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`'s default).

Is there a way to reference theme attributes in color selectors prior to API 21? (Using Support Library 25.3.0 if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

`?android:attr/colorBackground` is not defined prior to API 21.

When using AndroidX and material components it seems you can use `?attr/colorSurface` as it is the same color. I'm guessing you could just use it to avoid defining a specific resource for v21 and above.

Both background and surface values for material components are defined [there](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/values/colors.xml).